# Searching with selenium python if css atribute is set to a certain value

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Can I somehow check if 'cursor:' is set to 'auto' or 'zoom-in' using selenium?
This info is here:

```
<div id="ivLargeImage" style="height: 754px; display: block; opacity: 1; visibility: visible; cursor: auto;"><img src="https://m.media.com/images/I/41oy+cZNltL._AC_.jpg" class="fullscreen" style="margin-top: 127px; margin-left: 540.5px; height: 500px; width: 368px;"></div>
```

My program takes input 10Links for some products, and opens each one in a loop, it should check if 'cursor' atribute is set to 'zoom-in' , and the outputs only links where image has this 'zoom-in' value

Basically what I'm trying to do is this :

```
listofword = ['class="image item itemNo0 maintain-height selected" style="cursor: pointer;"'] 
driver.get(ProductLink) 
elm = driver.find_element_by_...I dont know how to point to this path (<li class="image item itemNo0 maintain-height selected" style="cursor: pointer;">)
if elm in listofword:
  print('passed')
```

If this 'class="image item itemNo0 maintain-height selected" style="cursor: pointer;"'   is present in the page source  print('passed')

or if above is not possible :

Search for this word "enlarge"

````
listofword = ['enlarge'] 
driver.get(ProductLink) 
elm = driver.find_element_by_...I dont know how to point to this path (<span id="canvasCaption" class="a-color-secondary">click here to enlarge</span>)
if elm in listofword:
  print('passed')```


If this  'enlarge'   is present in the page source  print('passed')
````

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the list of elements, extract the `style` attribute and check if it contains the desired substring.
Something like this:

```py
for element in elements:
    style = element.get_attribute("style")
    if "cursor: zoom-in" in style:
        #do what you want to do in this case
```

**UPD**
Similarly to the above, you can check in `class` attribute contains `style="cursor: pointer` as following:

```py
for element in elements:
    value = element.get_attribute("class")
    if 'style="cursor: pointer' in value:
        #do what you want to do in this case
```

Comment: It looks like, "cursor: zoom-in"  is available only after clicking the image first, so this is why it's not working.

Comment: Well, you asked how to check if css attribute is set to some value, not how to set it.

Comment: Meanwhile I have found this difference between a product page with zoom-in function and one without zoom-in function  :  ```<li class="image item itemNo0 maintain-height selected" style="cursor: pointer;">     VS      <li class="image item itemNo0 maintain-height selected">```  . This info is available when page loads (no need to click something).  How can I check if this (style="cursor: pointer;" )   is present on not for this class name ("image item itemNo0 maintain-height selected").  Just for one product page for example(so i can do my best to understand)

Comment: OK, I have updated the answer accordingly to your last comment. I hope this will be useful

Comment: "elements" should be defined somehow because I'm getting this : for element in elements:
NameError: name 'elements' is not defined  for this code: `DRIVER.get(ProductLink)
for element in elements:
    value = element.get_attribute("class")
    if  "cursor: pointer" in value:
        print('wow') `

Comment: Sure. What did you expect here? This is what you wrote in your question, no? You have a list of elements and you want to find an element with specific parameters.

Comment: "elements"  would be the list of product links ?

Comment: A list of elements possibly containing the `style="cursor: pointer` in their `class` attribute

Comment: did this resolve your problem?

Comment: No, not really .  Sorry it's me, I'm a bit of a noob.  Bassicaly what I'm trying to do is this `listofword = ['class="image item itemNo0 maintain-height selected" style="cursor: pointer;"'] 
driver.get(ProductLink) 
elm = driver.find_element_by_...I dont know how to point to this path (<li class="image item itemNo0 maintain-height selected" style="cursor: pointer;">)
if elm in listofword:
  print('passed')`

Comment: or if above is not possible :

 Search for this word "enlarge"


`listofword = ['enlarge'] 
driver.get(ProductLink) 
elm = driver.find_element_by_...I dont know how to point to this path (<span id="canvasCaption" class="a-color-secondary">click here to enlarge</span>)
if elm in listofword:
  print('passed')`

Comment: Please put all this in the question. It will be readable and more visible to all the users